# Update the number of nonlinear constraints in fmincon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to use `fmincon` in a `while` loop such that until the `while` condition is not satisfied, `fmincon` must be executed. Each time `fmincon` can't satisfy a specific condition (e.g., `x(N)-7.6==Tol`), the number `N` of nonlinear constraints should be updated (increased). How is this possible with `fmincon`?
Suppose I initially have 18 nonlinear equality equations (`ceq(1)` ... `ceq(18)`). When the `while` condition can't be satisfied, the number of nonlinear equality equations should be increased to 23 (`ceq(1)` ... `ceq(23)`) on the next iteration.

tnx for your innovative idea....let's give you more details about what I wanna do. I have some set of nonlinear algebraic equations so that I need to work with NLP (nonlinear programming) solvers. besides my cost function is minimum time problem. actually my nonlinear constrained equations are some dynamic governing equations which are discreticized in time coordinate. N is the number of discretization. based on Lagrange optimization technique, for finding optimal solution, gradient of scalar function(Lagrangian) should be added to system. as I mentioned in my question I need to test my problem with an initial N, then if the Xoutput of fmincon could'nt meet the constrained, it needs to increase the number of descritization. it continues, until the output optimal answer of fmincon get closed enough to my desired answer.

Comment: uhhh..... are the equations different? If {ceq(1), ... ceq(18)} cannot be satisfied, how can a superset of those equations be satisfied?

Comment: @MatthewGunn: `fmincon` performs local optimization so I suppose that adding additional constraints might force it to search in other parts of the space.

Comment: @horchler In general, you don't want non-linear equality constraints in an optimization problem. Try to minimize `(x-4).^2` subject to the constraint that `sin(x*pi)==0` using fmincon. The constraint constrains `x` to integer values, but fmincon will return completely non-sensical solutions (eg. `6.7109e+06`. If the gradient of your constraints do not describe the feasible set, all kinds of optimization algorithms blow up. I have no idea the specifics of Ali's problem, but my guess is that has *not* been formulated in a manner conducive to numerical optimizaiton techniques.

Comment: This rarely happens, but putting additional constraints can help in some occasions. When the obtained optimized point is not global minimum due to, for instance, unlucky starting point, finding the right starting point can be problematic due to the large number of variables. So, putting additional constraints can push the solution into the desired direction.

Answer (score 1):

Peeling back the onion, it appears to me your question doesn't address your real problem, and you're going about solving your problem numerically in somewhat the wrong way. How you solve a problem numerically is related but rather different to how you would solve a problem analytically, writing out equations by hand. See my further comment at the end, and I'd advise talking to fellow students, fellow students in your lab, and/or the prof.

#### Several comments:

1. Your objective funciton `@(x) norm(myfoctest(x))` will *always* return 0 because myfoctest returns the empty array `[]` as its first argument, and in Matlab, `norm([])` is defined as 0.
2. Instead of `minimize 0 subject to f(x)==0`, it appears you *intend* to solve problem `minimize norm(f(x)) subject to f(x)==0`? I don't understand the purpose of constraint f(x)==0 in this context. Why not `minimize norm(f(x))`?
3. In your function, `myfoctest` Why is `Ceq(2*N)=x(5*N+12)-x(5*N+11)-x(4*N+2)` in the for loop? You're assigning the value of `x(32)- x(31) - x(18)` to `Ceq(8)` four separate times (i.e. for j=1:4). Is this what you intend? This error suggests to me there might be other errors in the way you've written `myfoctest`.
4. A number of these constraints are linear constraints. Entering them as non-linear constraints will make fmincon's job harder.
5. I don't know the original problem, but this *feels* to me that you're going about numerically solving it in a haphazard, screwy way. I've spotted several errors just glancing at the code, and I'd be concerned there are more if I actually understood the problem.
6. You have `5*N+13` variables and `5*N+13` non-linear equality constraints. Your feasible set may be a single point! Digression: many optimization algorithms start with a feasible point and take a step in a feasible direction. If the feasible set is a single point, there's no feasible direction... In your problem, the whole game is finding the one feasible point (if it even exists)?!
7. I doubt the main problem is that you need to "Update the number of nonlinear constraints in fmincon in Matlab."
8. It vaguely sounds like you've calculated the first order conditions of the Lagrangian, and you're entering those as constraints for the optimization problem? If so, that's *very likely not what you should be doing* to solve numerically.

#### Some suggestions...

1. I think you need to take a step back to the beginning: write down what you're trying to solve in a clean way, and then figure out how to solve it numerically in an efficient manner. My gut reaction is that this so far is a somewhat confused mess.

#### Further comment

Say you have some minimization problem (eg. an optimal control problem):

```
minimize f(x) subject to g(x) <= 0.
```

where f and g and convex, Slater's condition holds, and the first order conditions are necessary and sufficient conditions to achieve a minimum. You might solve this mathematically and get some first order conditions:

```
dL/dx = 0
```

You might think that the way to solve this problem numerically is to numerically solve the system of equations dL/dx (from the FOC). If dL/dx is a system of linear equations, this might be true, but in general, that's often an intractable way to go about solving the problem. Instead, you want to feed `f` and `g` directly to your optimization algorithms.

General points to keep in mind:

- Solving a system of linear equations is efficient and fast.
- Solving a convex optimization problem is efficient and fast.
- In general, solving a system of non-linear equations or non-convex optimization can be horrible, horrible problems.

Comment: @ Matthew ....you're absolutely right. to fix comment 3,I take the constant equations out of for loop...of course I didn't want to produce the same equations more and more...I just need to make the all set of equations once, solve them and by increasing the  variable N, converge to my desired value

Comment: @ Matthew    I actually want to solve  a system of nonlinear algebraic equations simultaneously. so I take my chance with fmincon. truly the general idea is to solve the constrained, and cause in fmincon you need to call an objective function I choose the norm of my set of equations. I try to solve them with fsolve. but it didn't give the right answer.  .

Comment: @Ali Where do the algebraic equations come from?

Comment: I tried the common rules first...I mean putting the nonlinear constrained and objective function in separate m.files  and just call them in fmincon....but there is a problem...my set of equations have 2 be a function of descrtization levels...so if fmincon fails to achieve the desired states, N goes up and the whole set of equations would be updated....after that the new set of nonlinear equations (mytestfoc) should be solved

Comment: @Matthew....there is an algorithm namely Fuzzy optimal control (FOC) approach. some dynamic equations come from aerospace application in transfer orbit maneuver which should be discritized and the other come from the original algorithm.

Comment: this approach(FOC) is applicable to solve classical optimal control problem. these set of equations are exerted from the last part of algorithm which applied optimality condition and calculate the gradient of Lagrangian

Comment: From what I can tell, you do *not* have a straightforward programming problem. You have a complicated, mathematics problem.  How you solve a large system of non-linear algebraic equations is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @Ali is this correct: (1) there exists some optimal control problem you are trying to solve (2) this optimal control problem is convex and something like Slater's condition is satisfied, hence the first order conditions are necessary and sufficient conditions for an optimum and (3) you are trying to solve this system of equations?

Comment: @ Matthew  the 1st point is right....abt the second I could tell you that this problem could transfer to parameter optimization problem but according to the algorithm we must exerted Lagrange optimization technique. by solving the set of equations come from optimality conditions in lagrange optimizations and solve system of eqations simultaneously optimal solution is acheivable

Comment: Is there any better idea to solve a set of NAE equations simultaneously? besides it's good to know that since the analytical solution of this case of study is accessible for me, I can replace some part of initial guess vector with analytic solution....so that algorithm can escape from trap of usual gradient-based algorithm(local minima)

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases. In first, some condition is satisfied, and in second, it's not. Make the `while` statement hold true in each case. In your loop add the flag variable that would change its value if your condition is not satisfied. For example you can put something like:

```
flag = (x(N)-7.6<Tol);
```

that would return `1` if condition is satisfied and `0` otherwise.

In your `mycon` function add `flag` as an input variable:

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(all_variables_you_had_before,flag)
```

Then, add the logical block in `mycon` looking like:

```
if flag == 1
    ceq = [___]; %//put your 18 conditions here
else
    ceq = [___]; %//put your 23 conditions here
end
```

Finally, do not forget to add `mycon(all_variables_you_had_before,flag)` in the `fmincon` line in your main script:

```
x = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@(all_variables_you_had_before) mycon(all_variables_you_had_before,flag))
```

So, if the condition is satisfied, your `fmincon` would get the constraints as usual. But if the condition is not satisfied, the constraints would change. Hope that helps.

Comment: that's really helpful....but how can I change 'mycon' file to the one that depend on the N? (cause there aren't fixed number of nonlinear constrained equations)...I have to use this flag in such a way that it could be implemented according to the variable number of conditions per run of fmincon.

Comment: Yep. In this case, your flag becomes not binary number, but something like: `if {condition1};flag=0; elseif {condition2};flag=1; elseif {condition 3}; flag=2; ...add more layers here...`

Comment: @Ali and in your `mycon` file your conditions would be like `switch(flag); case(0);{do this};case(1);{do this};case(2);{do this} etc. `

Comment: the condition would be the same, but it's the matter of the number of times I have to use this flag. suppose that I have a large-scale constraints (e.g N=100), so each time I have to write and call this flag. I meant in this specific case I have to noted if flag=1 {condition1};.....flag=100 {condition100}. I'm sure there should be a way to relate the number of flags to number of nonlinear conditions in code

Comment: You have a really peculiar situation. In `mycon` you can specify the vector with all the conditions e.g. `v=[__]; %//size is 100`. Then, type `ceq = v(1:flag)`. This way you would get as many constraints as large your flag is. That's all I can say with information provided

Answer (score 0):

```
function [x]=runnested(x0,N)
 r=ones(4,1);
N=length(r);
Tol=0.001;
for k=1:N
for i=1:N
x0=rand(5*N+13,1)
options = optimset('Largescale','off','algorithm','interior-point','Display','iter');
[x(i,:),fval,exitflag,output]=fmincon(@(x) norm(myfoctest(x)),x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@myfoctest,options)
end
if x(N)-7.61<=Tol
  break;
else
  N=N+1;  
end
 end
 function [C,Ceq]=myfoctest(x,N,r)
 C=[];
 r=ones(4,1); 
N=length(r);
f=3.5e-6; %km/s^2
i1=10*(pi/180); 
Ts=110;    %sec   
V0=7.79;    %km/sec
a1=7.61;         %km/sec
b1=0.01*a1;
a2=20*(pi/180);  % rad      %10 deg
b2=0.01*a2;  %rad 
Omeg0=10*(pi/180);  %rad
Ceq=zeros(5*N+13,1);     
   for j=1:N-1
    Ceq(j)=x(3*N+1+j)-  x(3*N+j)-2*x(4*N+1+j)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*sin(i1)*x(j)^2)
    Ceq(N)=x(5*N+10)-x(5*N+9)-x(3*N+2)   %x(5*N+10)-x(5*N+9)-x(4*N+7)
    Ceq(N+j)=x(4*N+1+j)-x(4*N+j)
    Ceq(2*N)=x(5*N+12)-x(5*N+11)-x(4*N+2)
    Ceq(2*N+1)=x(3*N+1)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1))+2*x(4*N+1)*Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1))/(pi*V0*sin(i1))
    Ceq(2*N+1+j)=x(3*N+1+j)*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))+2*x(4*N+1+j)*Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*x(j)*sin(i1))
    Ceq(3*N+1)=1-x(5*N+9)*b1-x(5*N+10)*b1-x(5*N+11)*b2-x(5*N+12)*b2-x(5*N+8)*N*Ts/100-x(5*N+13)
    Ceq(3*N+2)=-2*x(5*N+8)*x(5*N+2)
    Ceq(3*N+3)=-2*x(5*N+9)*x(5*N+3)
    Ceq(3*N+4)=-2*x(5*N+10)*x(5*N+4)
    Ceq(3*N+5)=-2*x(5*N+11)*x(5*N+5)
    Ceq(3*N+6)=-2*x(5*N+12)*x(5*N+6)
    Ceq(3*N+7)=2*x(5*N+13)*cos(x(5*N+7))*sin(x(5*N+7))
    Ceq(3*N+8)=V0-x(1)-Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1))
    Ceq(3*N+8+j)=x(j)-x(j+1)-Ts*f*cos(x(2*N+1+j))
    Ceq(4*N+8)=Omeg0-x(N+1)+2*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1))/(pi*V0*sin(i1))
    Ceq(4*N+8+j)=Omeg0-x(j+1)+2*Ts*f*sin(x(2*N+1+j))./(pi*x(j)*sin(i1))
    Ceq(5*N+8)=-x(5*N+2)^2-N*Ts/100-N*Ts*x(3*N+1)/100
    Ceq(5*N+9)=-x(5*N+3)^2-x(N)+a1+b1-b1*x(3*N+1)+7.61/100
    Ceq(5*N+10)=-x(5*N+4)^2+x(N)+a1+b1-b1*x(3*N+1)-7.61/100
    Ceq(5*N+11)=-x(5*N+5)^2-x(2*N)+a2+b2-b2*x(3*N+1)+0.35/100
    Ceq(5*N+12)=-x(5*N+6)^2+x(2*N)+a2+b2-b2*x(3*N+1)-0.35/100
    Ceq(5*N+13)=-(sin(x(5*N+7)))^2-x(5*N+1)
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: actually I should notice that this series of nonlinear algebraic equations need to be created iteratively, based on parameter N. (N is the number of discritization)

Comment: according to the if condition if it couldn't be satisfied the N should be increased  in myfoctest so the number of equations would grow by 5(5 number of equations would be added in each time). I wonder ,first,is there any way to write these equations in vectorized form or may put them in an array?

Comment: FYI, `@(x) norm(myfoctest(x))` will ALWAYS return 0. myfoctest returns [] as the first argument and norm of [] in Matlab is defined as 0.

Comment: @ Matthew   is there any way to get rid of this empty value?